# Closed form of $ \int_0^\infty x e^{-b \pi x^2}(1+x^{-a})^{-n}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals

> Is there an exact closed-form expression or a closed-form upper bound for the following integral?
>   $$I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x e^{-b \pi x^2}}{(1+x^{-a})^{n}}\mathrm{d}x, \tag1$$
>   where $a > 2$, $b, n > 0$.
>   If yes, how can we obtain it?

**My attempt**: If we multiply $I$ in $(1)$ by $2\pi b$, we get the probability density function of Rayleigh random variable, i.e, $f_X(x) = 2\pi b xe^{-b \pi x^2}$. So we can write $I$ as
$$I = \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\frac{1}{1+X^{-a}}\right)^{n}\right].$$
I could not procced in this way.

Comment: Bounds are simple to derive from the CS inequality or other techniques. I would not bet on the existence of a simple closed form.

Comment: Any hint on how to begin with CS inequality?

Comment: The usual way: write the integrand function as the product of two functions with an easily integrable square and almost the same behaviour in a right neighbourhood of the origin.

Comment: @user399601: that does not work. Otherwise you would be able to compute $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)e^{x^2}}$ through the residue theorem, too.

Comment: Oh. Can you please elaborate on it? When $a$ is an integer, it is a useful case.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio You're right. It's because $\frac{-ze^{-b\pi z^2} \log(z)}{(1+z^{-a})^n}$ doesn't satisfy good growth conditions (it grows way too quickly to use the contour I had in mind) I always forget to check that.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I tried applying CS inequality: The first integral of CS inequality becomes $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+x^{-a})^{2n}}\mathrm{d}x$, which seems to diverge. Is this observation correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x e^{-b \pi x^2}}{(1+x^{-a})^{n}}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$I = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-b \pi t}}{(1+t^{-a/2})^{n}}\mathrm{d}t\qquad\text{with}\quad t=x^2$$
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\mathscr{L}_t\left[\frac{1}{(1+t^{-a/2})^{n}}\right](b\pi)$$
$\mathscr{L}$ denotes the Laplace transform.

The hitch is that no closed form exists in the most extended tables of Laplace transform for the general form of this function. So, probably one cannot express the integral on a closed form in the general case (any $a$ and $n$).
Of course, closed form exist in particular cases. For example :

$n=1\:,\:a=2 \quad\to\quad I=\frac{1}{2b\pi}+\frac{1}{2}e^{b\pi}\mathrm{Ei}(-b\pi)\qquad \text{: Exponential integral}$

$n=1\:,\:a=4 \quad\to\quad I=\frac{1}{2b\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\cos(b\pi)\left(\mathrm{Si}(b\pi)-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\sin(b\pi)\mathrm{Ci}(b\pi) \quad$
where Si and Ci are the sin and cos integrals.

Comment: How can we prove the results you provided for particular cases?

Comment: Integrate by parts and use the definition of the functions Exponential integral and/or Sin and Cos integral.

Answer (score 0):

WolframAlpha ist able to compute the anti-derivative of your integrand for $a=2$ and small fixed integer $n$. From these solutions I came up with a conjecture for $a=2$ and general integer $n$.

Some notation:

$$ I_{a,n}(c)= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x e^{-c x^2}}{(1+x^{-a})^{n}}\mathrm{d}x, \tag1$$
where $a > 2$, $c, n > 0$.

The conjecture for $a=2$:
$$ F_{2,n}(x,c)= \int\frac{x e^{-c x^2}}{(1+x^{-2})^{n}}\mathrm{d}x = p_1(c) ~ \mathrm{e}^c ~ \mathrm{Ei}(-c(x^2+1)) - \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-cx^2}~p_2(c,x)}{c(x^2+1)^{n-1}}$$

$$ I_{2,n}(c) = -F_{2,n}(0,c) = -p_1(c) ~ \mathrm{e}^c ~ \mathrm{Ei}(-c) + \frac{p_2(c,0)}{c}$$

Where $p_1(c)$ is a polynomial in $c$ of degree $n-1$ and $p_2(x,c)$ is a polynomial in $c$ of degree $n-1$ and in $x$ of degree $2(n-1)$ with only even terms in $x$.
I don't have a general form for $p_1$ and $p_2$, but using the above restrictions it's possible to solve for their coefficients given some fixed $n$ by differentiating $F_{2,n}$ and comparing with the integrand.

Some solutions:
$$I_{2,1} = \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)\mathrm{e}^c \mathrm{Ei}(-c) +
\frac{1}{c}\left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \text{(already given by JJacquelin)}$$
$$I_{2,2} = \left(\frac{1}{2} \, c + 1 \right)\mathrm{e}^c
\mathrm{Ei}(-c) + \frac{1}{c}\left( \frac{1}{2} \, c + \frac{1}{2}
\right)$$
$$I_{2,3} = \left(\frac{1}{4} \, c^{2} + \frac{3}{2} \, c + \frac{3}{2}
\right)\mathrm{e}^c \mathrm{Ei}(-c) + \frac{1}{c}\left( \frac{1}{4} \,
c^{2} + \frac{5}{4} \, c + \frac{1}{2} \right)$$
$$I_{2,4} = \left(\frac{1}{12} \, c^{3} + c^{2} + 3 \, c + 2
\right)\mathrm{e}^c \mathrm{Ei}(-c) + \frac{1}{c}\left( \frac{1}{12} \,
c^{3} + \frac{11}{12} \, c^{2} + \frac{13}{6} \, c + \frac{1}{2}
\right)$$